# Delete button on Mini cart popup not working and turning screen black on home page magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I'm having an issue on magento 2.2,

The Delete button on Mini cart popup is not working and turning screen black on home page

strangely when you click the delete icon the screen just darkens and and gets darker every time you press it until its just black,

This image is before you click the delete icon:

[image: image.png]

here it is after clicking it:

[image]

and it gets darker on every press,

This doesn't happen when not on the home page,

in other pages such as the catalog, you can just delete from the cart normally,

anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance,

Gavin

Comment: did you see any error in your browser console?

Comment: @magefms no not seeing any errors..any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: honestly, I haven't met that kind of issue before but I think it has something to do with the button class conflict with some classes on the homepage. Maybe you can start debugging by changing your theme to the default one and check if the issue still persists.